# Lattice xyplot won't show one of the plots

Tags: r, lattice

I can't use xyplot to plot multiple time series. It might have something to do with the difference in the amount of data points?

```
dim(no_na2[no_na2$weektype=="weekend",])
# [1] 4032    5
dim(no_na2[no_na2$weektype=="weekday",])
# [1] 11232     5
```

scales=="free" doesn't work. Is there a certain kind of axes adjustment that would?

```
xyplot((int_avg~x|weektype), data=no_na2, type="l", xlab="Interval", ylab="Steps")
```

What I get:

[image]

I can't get the first one to show up.

Reproducible example:

```
int <- c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20)
weektype <- c("weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekday", "weekend", "weekend")
steps <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2)
data.frame(weektype, steps, int)
xyplot(steps~unique(int)|weektype, data=ex1, type="l", xlab="Interval", ylab="Steps")
```

What I get trying to do a time series plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzEnI.jpg

What I get for int instead of unique(int): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTx9x.jpg

Comment: Ok, I have added it @MrFlick. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I'm not sure this example makes any sense to me. What are you trying to do with `unique()` here? That will change the length of `int` which will make it impossible to plot. how does the plot know which values of steps should be plotted with each int?

Comment: I see, thank you, that solved my problem. lol @MrFlick